# Tao Analysis 1 Exercise 6.1.8.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $(b_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers and let $L$ be a real number such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n = L$. Let also $b_n \neq 0$ for all n and $L \neq 0$. Show that

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{b_n} = \frac{1}{L}.
\end{equation*}
I do not understand the hint behind the exercise. The hint states that one should prove that the sequence is bounded away from zero. However, if $b_n \neq 0$ for all $n$ why do I need to prove such a thing? In particular, can someone point out where the mistake is in my reasoning?

My proof:
Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = L$ the sequence is bounded; i.e., there exists a $B>0$ such that $|b_n|\leq B$ for all $n$. Observe that

\begin{align}
|\frac{1}{b_n} - \frac{1}{L}| &= |\frac{L-b_n}{b_nL}|\\
&= \frac{|b_n - L|}{|b_n||L|}\\
&\leq \frac{|b_n - L|}{B|L|}.
\end{align}

Choosing now an appropriate $\epsilon$ for $|b_n - L|$ like $\epsilon B|L|$ should be sufficient to conclude the reasoning.

Comment: To pass from the second to last line to the last, you need that $b_n$ is bounded below by $B>0$.

Comment: You forgot to add the assumption that $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=L$. As it reads now, $L$ is just any real number completely unrelated to $\{b_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq m}}$.

Comment: You are right. I will add that it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last step goes from $|b_n| \leq B$ to $\frac{1}{|b_n|} \leq \frac{1}{B}$, which does not follow (the inequality goes the wrong way).

If you knew that $|b_n| \geq  B$ for all large enough $n$ then you'd be able to use that estimate to get $\frac{1}{|b_n|} \leq \frac{1}{B}$ as you wished.  Showing $|b_n| \geq B$ for all large enough $n$ is exactly what the hint you were given means.

Answer (score 2):

$|b_n|\le M$ implies $\frac{1}{|b_n|}\ge \frac{1}{M}$

$\frac{|b_n - L|}{|b_n||L|}
\leq \frac{|b_n - L|}{B|L|}$ ❌

Hint for the correct proof:

$b_n\to L$ and $L\neq 0$ implies $\exists N\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\ge N$ ,$|b_n|\ge \frac{|L|}{2}$

( use $\epsilon=\frac{|L|}{2}$ in $b_n\to L$ )

Answer (score 2):

The bound you have imposed is that $\lvert b_n\rvert\leq B$ for all $n$, and while this can be done, it's not what you want, and is not what the hint is telling you. Indeed it is **not true** that

$$\frac{\lvert b_n-L\rvert}{\lvert b_n\rvert\lvert L\rvert}\leq\frac{\lvert b_n-L\rvert}{B\lvert L\rvert},$$

but **the reverse inequality is true**. That is why it does not help you. Now what the hint tells you to do is show the existence of some $C>0$ such that $C\leq \lvert b_n\rvert$ for all $n$. If you can do this, then just replace $B$ with $C$ in your argument and all is good.